# Aligning li Elements in a Div

Tags: html, css, web

I need to align 3 different elements in my div.
They are in a ul list:
Left, Center and Right.

I tried to use float: right for the right element, and margin: 0 auto with a width for the element in the center. But still it doesn't align automatically.

The elements can also be images, not only text. 
http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/3/ check this out

Comment: mh .. thanks, but the "Right" should also float to the right, in a fluid style.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/5/ check this one...

Comment: thanks, but still doesn't work when resizing the page. I think the other posted answer is right.

Comment: Give `text-align` `left` , `center` and `right` to `li's` with same `width's`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:table` and `table-cell` may be your solution. Here is the [fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/2/).

Later edit: [Reworked example](http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/7/)

Comment: Thanks, this works for me ! Only had to set width to 100% in the ul. Will this also work with images, and will the image then be centered as well in the "Center" container ?

Comment: Yes, if you put the image in `.Middle` element. Here is the [Reworked example](http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/7/)

Comment: Here is [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/8/) (with an image in the center).

Comment: Wow, thanks. You're great :) Is it also possible to align the text vertically in the middle with the image by using "vertical-align" ? http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/9/

Comment: Sure. Add `.Navigation img { vertical-align: middle; }` to css rules.

Comment: mh.. though the image is not centered with the text http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/10/

Comment: add also this: `.Navigation li#Middle { vertical-align: middle; }`

Comment: OK, I got it working, but do you know how I can fix it to the very bottom of the page (end of height viewport)? I tried several approaches, but it didn't really work.
http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/11/

Comment: The entire `ul` element? Just apply `position: fixed; bottom: 0;` [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PwmrC/12/) is the example. If you want it at the bottom of some `div` container then `position:absolute` to navigation ul, and for parent div/container a `position` different from "static" (e.g. relative, absolute, fixed).